# Is it possible to find all strings that are 8 characters long in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I know strlen is used to determine the string length - but is it possible to search an entire block of text and pull out strings that are exactly 8 characters long?

Comment: something on the lines of .(8,8) in regexp

Comment: What would `abcdefghij` give you? `abcdefgh`, `bcdefghi`, `cdefghij`?

Comment: good point @ThiefMaster - I will play with the examples below all seem to be sufficient for now. thanks again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following assumes by "strings exactly eight characters long" you mean "words", e.g. in a text like

```
$blockOfText = <<< TXT
codepad is an online compiler/interpreter, and a simple collaboration tool.
Paste your code below, and codepad will run it and give you a short URL you 
can use to share it in chat or email. 
TXT;
```

you want to find the word "compiler" only.

---

### Non-Regex solution ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XxofNm)):

```
print_r(
    array_filter(
        str_word_count($blockOfText, 1),
        function($word) { return strlen($word) === 8; }
    )
);
```

#### Reference:

- [`str_word_count` — Return information about words used in a string](http://php.net/str_word_count)
- [`array_filter` — Filters elements of an array using a callback function](http://php.net/array_filter)
- [Callbacks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)
- [Anonymous Functions](http://php.net/closures)

---

### Regex solution ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yfFYV1)):

```
preg_match_all(
    '(
        \b     # match from a word boundary
        \w{8}  # followed by exactly 8 "word" characters
        \b     # followed by a word boundary
    )x', 
    $blockOfText, 
    $matches
);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

> A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character, that is, any character which can be part of a Perl "word". The definition of letters and digits is controlled by PCRE's character tables, and may vary if locale-specific matching is taking place. For example, in the "fr" (French) locale, some character codes greater than 128 are used for accented letters, and these are matched by \w.

#### Reference:

- [`preg_match_all` — Perform a global regular expression match](http://php.net/preg_match_all)
- [PCRE Pattern Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode()` or `preg_split()` to split teh string by your delimiter(s) and iterate over the result array and use `strlen()`.

Simple example, finds everything with a length of 2:

```
$string = "abcd ab abc abd ad";
$array = explode(' ', $string);
foreach ($array as $part) {
    if (strlen($part) == 2) {
        echo '"' . $part . '" has a length of 2<br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all("/\b[a-zA-Z]{8}\b/", $sText, $aMatches);
$aWords = $aMatches[0];
```

Also see [this example](http://ideone.com/00ZOq).